# Can I use dd to upgrade 1-bay synology NAS to bigger HD?

Tags: hard-drive, nas, clone, dd, synology

I have a 1-bay Synology NAS (DS112). According to the [Synology compatibility](https://www.synology.com/en-us/compatibility/hd/DS112) list it can take a 6TB disk. If possible I'd like to clone my existing 2TB disk to the 6TB disk using `dd` or any other tool easily available on the NAS.

This is my plan:

1. Put the new HD into an SATA to USB box.
2. Connect it to the NAS via USB.
3. Use `dd` to clone the existing 2TB HD to the new 6TB HD.
4. Use Clonzilla on a PC to change the partition size.
5. Repalce the old HD with the new one in the Synology.

Any one tried this or did something similar? Other strategies which avoid setting-up the NAS from scratch are welcome as well. I'm also not sure how to find the correct device names for the disks and what options to use for `dd`.

Comment: Why not simply set up the 6TB into the NAS, and then the 2TB in an external enclosure and then start copying?

Comment: I'd like to avoid to do the whole configuration again. Setting up all applications and users from scratch would be a lot of work.

Comment: Synology has their own Backup and Restore. You should be able to backup the configuration and then restore it, and it should restore the configuration and any applications that you got configured from their store.... tho I'm sorry to say I haven't tested this but thats what they claim on their backup and restore